# ComboBox Items values are switched

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox on a Winform app that contains a list of regular expressions that match `date` formats. I load the ComboBox using a Dictionary so I can display an example of a matching pattern and have the actual regular expression as the `SelectedValue`.

```
  Dictionary<string, string> datePatternsSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  datePatternsSource.Add(@"dd-MMM-yy (05-SEP-15)", @"((\d{2})(\-)(\w{3})(\-)(\d{2}))");
  datePatternsSource.Add(@"yyyy-MM-dd (2015-09-05)", @"((\d{4})(\-)(\d{2})(\-)(\d{2}))");
  datePatternsSource.Add(@"MM/dd/yyyy (09/05/2015)", @"((\d{2})(\/)(\d{2})(\/)(\d{4}))");
  datePatternsSource.Add(@"M/d/yyyy (9/5/2015)", @"((\d{1,2})(\/)(\d{1,2})(\/)(\d{4}))");
  datePatternsSource.Add(@"yyyy/MM/dd (2015/09/05)", @"((\d{4})(\/)(\d{2})(\/)(\d{2}))");

  cboDatePatterns.DisplayMember = "Key";
  cboDatePatterns.ValueMember = "Value";
  cboDatePatterns.DataSource = new BindingSource(datePatternsSource, null);
```

The problem is that two of the regular expressions are not matching to the proper example. To demonstrate I call the MessageBox.Show() method to display the combobox properties.

```
MessageBox.Show("SelectedItem = " + cboDatePatterns.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\nSelectedValue = " + cboDatePatterns.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

[image: The comboBox]
[image: Correct match]
[image: Incorrect match]

How could these values be switched? Three out of the five items are matched correctly. Two of them are switched.

Comment: I just used your code and it works without problem to me. No "switching" of the values...

Comment: Is `Sorted` true for your ComboBox?

Comment: Wow... @Andy, I change the Sorted to true and was able to reproduce the behavior pointed by webworm. I wouldn't expect this to happen... Is this as it should be?

Comment: After looking here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, I found that if you set the "Sorted" to true on a databound combobox on designtime, you have this behaviour, while if you set it during runtime, after the databound was set, you receive the argument exception. So, the Sorted must not be used with databound...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, I found that if you set the `Sorted` to `true` on a databound combobox on designtime, you have this behavior, while if you set it during runtime, after the databound was set, you raise an argument exception. So, the Sorted must not be used with databound combobox...

If you want the values to be sorted, you have to sort them through the Dictionary.

Or, probably best, like pointed by @Andy, Using a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).
I tested and it worked, of course. Thanks @Andy. :)

Comment: Maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx would work too?

Comment: Thank you! Very nice find. I don't think I would have ever figured that one out.